# How to capture dynamic dependent drop down values in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I have to capture dynamic dependent dropdown values.

For example. I want to capture district in second dropdown based on selected State in first Dropdown using loadrunner

Answer (score 0):

If this is pulled from the server based upon your first selection, i.e. a query is made when you select country to populate the list for states/regions, then you use standard correlation techniques to pull the data and populate variables for use.   If this happens 100% on the client where the populated values of the second list are calculated and populated from local JavaScript then you have three options:

- Reproduce the algorithm in your code which runs locally to populate the local variables and then select from the available options
- Reduce the complexity to the number of permutation of data in your parameter file.   Don't worry about running local code simply populate the values you need from your local parameter data supplied for the virtual user
- Run a full client which runs the browser and JavaScript (assuming this is a browser based question.  The options here are TruClient, Citrix or Remote Desktop.